# How to display specific user data in wpf window from sql database?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am working on a simple wpf project. There are three forms first is Login form,2nd is Registration form and 3rd is profile form. The project requirement is when i register any user on registration page it redirects me to the profile form and show me complete profile of the user just created.

```
  private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

            if (txtUsername.Text  ==  ""  ||
                txtPasswd.Text    ==  ""  ||
                txtName.Text      ==  ""  ||
                txtEmail.Text     ==  ""  ||
                txtMobile.Text    ==  "" 
               )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill the empty fields", "Warning");
            }
            else
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    string queryString = "Insert Into tblLogin Values(@Username,@Password,@Name,@Email,@Mobile)";

                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email", "Error");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtUsername.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtPasswd.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtName.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtMobile.Text;

                        con.Open();
                        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("Registration completed");
                    }

                }
```

After completing registration i want to display the user profile just created but on another page.Can anyone help me how to do this.Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx). Then will be interesting if you read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kaps_deo/create-navigation-based-application-in-wpf/) and try with [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation).

Hope it helps.